# Как я могу собрать статику в рабочем проекте django?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Есть сайт который работает на debian9.0 + django + guncorn + nginx + systemd.

Я разрабатываю дополнения локально потом делаю `git pull` на github.

Иногда мне приходится вносить изменения в базу данных(новые страницы через админку и статические файлы(например цвет фона и или картинку)

Затем иду на сервер и делаю

`git pull`

Вылезает ошибка связанная с базой данной sqllitedb 
Делаю

`git stash`

Еще раз

`git pull`

И ошибка проходит, новые страницы и текст и ссылки меняются.(но стили не меняются)
Это и понятно ведь мы собрали всю статику в отдельную папку из которой nginx , берет ее.
Как мне собрать статику ? просто выключить gunicorn и сделать

`manage.py collectstatic?`

Насколько правильно использовать `git stash` в этой ситуации?
Очень долго разбирался с деплоем боюсь сломать)))(Может имеет смысл менять стили прямо в папке сss из которых берет их берет nginx и не парится?
Буду благодарен любым мыслям и советам!

Comment: Вы храните sqlite3-базу в git, что ли? Это очень плохо

Comment: Команда collectstatic выполняет копирование статики из всех Django-приложений в каталог, который указан в настройке STATIC_ROOT, и выключать gunicorn для её выполнения необязательно

Comment: Почему плохо? я знаю что ее используют для небольших сайтов и бэк-энда мобильных приложений

Comment: добавить файл базы данных в `.gitignore` и не синхронить ее через git. Заливать отдельно через ssh или ftp.

Comment: Какие плюсы мне это дает?Могу ли я пользоваться git stash?

Comment: Не надо вообще ничего заливать, база создаётся один раз при первом запуске проекта и дальше используется до бесконечности. База данных является не частью кода проекта, а результатом работы проекта, и хранить её в git как минимум нелогично. У отдельных независимо запущенных копий проекта вполне могут быть свои отдельные базы, со своими отдельными пользователями, постами и всем прочим, и силком их объединять, помещая базу в общий для всех git, неразумно.

Comment: Если же существуют данные, которые должны быть одинаковыми для всех копий проекта (например, список стран или предустановленные категории чего-нибудь), то такие данные помещаются в json-файл фикстур и затем загружаются в базу во время обновления проекта командой loaddata. А для чего-нибудь сложного, если возможностей фикстур не хватает, можно написать кастомную миграцию.

Comment: @andreymal согласен, но заливать таки надо иногда. Лучше это делать через накатывание бэкапов, но в случае с sqlite можно и просто скопировать файлик. Не вижу в этом ничего криминального.

Comment: А если идет доработка функционала и меняются модели!?

Comment: @OmertaOmerta изменения моделей применяются с помощью миграций, вы вроде бы должны были узнать об этом из какого-нибудь туториала про Django

Comment: Все верно,но иногда добавляется функционал , личный кабинет , корзина и т.д.

Comment: Ведь это тоже влияет на б.д. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @OmertaOmerta когда вашим приложением начнут пользоваться реальные пользователи, они тоже начнут менять БД. И каждый раз, когда вы будете копировать свою базу на прод, вы будете перезатирать их данные. Следовательно все системные изменения тоже нужно производить в формате миграций. Либо, если вы очень хотите создавать данные через админку или еще как-то через интерфейс - тогда нужно выполнять идентичные действия на проде и на тесте.

Comment: И хотя бы по этой причине, бд нужно исключить из репозитория. Даже если вынести за скобки безопасность данных. Может быть в вашем проекте она не так важна. Плюс - если вы переедете на базу данных посерьезнее, типа postgres или mysql, вы уже никак не сможете ее хранить в репозитории, потомому что она не будет храниться в одном файле.

Comment: Константин спасибо огромное за информацию!И вам Андрей!